# Not receiving C2DM message

Tags: android, android-c2dm, htc-thunderbolt

I have an app with C2DM currently implemented. I had it working to the point where I was receiving messages. Then a few days later I ran it on the same device and it was not receiving messages. The device is an HTC Thunderbolt. I ran the app on two other devices, an HTC Incredible and an HTC Evo, and it was working fine, receiving messages. I tried un-registering and re-registering the device with C2DM on the app. I was able to confirm that the device received a registration response, but still no messages.

Is it possible that this has something to do with my phone's settings? Perhaps it has to do with the associated Google account? I'm puzzled by why this has stopped working on this one particular device. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I had tried uninstalling, turning the phone off, back on, reinstalling before I posted on SO, but I guess I hadn't. After trying it (again?), it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same Google email for the phone that you are using as the dev Google email for the C2DM app?  I've had issues when not using different gmail aliases between the phone and the app dev email.

Comment: None of the devices that I am using to test are associated with the google account that I am using as the dev address.